# Get Entity ID after executing Native insert query + Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using a Native query in my JPA Repository to run INSERT query - because, I couldn't run a few queries through JPA.

```java
String INSERT_USER_IN_TO_DATABASE = "INSERT INTO USER_MASTER " +
            "(" +
            "MOBILE_X,USER_TYPE,COUNTRYCODE,USER_N,USER_LAST_N,GENDER,DOB) " +
            "VALUES ( " +
            "EncryptByKey(Key_GUID(convert(varchar,?1)), ?2)," +
            "1,+91,?3,?4,?5,?6" +
            ")";

    @Query(value = INSERT_USER_IN_TO_DATABASE, nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    UserMasterEntity saveNewUser(String encryptionKey,
                                 String phoneNumber,
                                 String name,
                                 String lastName,
                                 String gender,
                                 String dob);
```

My intention is to execute the `INSERT` statement and get me the userMaster entity. But I get the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type! Offending method: public abstract com.officeride.fileprocess.job.bulkuser.UserMasterEntity com.officeride.fileprocess.job.bulkuser.UserMasterRepository.saveNewUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

I used `@ColumnTransformer` stuff too in my entity and nothing is working out for me.

How to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make the `INSERT INTO` statement return anything. Depending on your database's support, on that end you could execute multiple statements, e.g., `INSERT INTO ...; SELECT ...`, but Spring Data JDBC does not support this.

- What you can do is implement `saveNewUser` and perform the insert then select, sequentially and synchronously. See this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior.
- If your database supports it, you could create a stored procedure that performs the insert then select.